# OptimizePress Theme Overriding add_filter page_template

Tags: themes, filters, page-template

I have a custom plugin running the following function to change the page template for my predefined pages.  It runs fine on the default 2017 theme but is being overridden by the OptimizePressTheme.

```
function _plc_page_template ($template) {
    $pages = _plc_get_custom_pages();   
    foreach ($pages as $slug => $title) {
        if (is_page ($slug) && is_file (PLC_TEMPLATES . $slug . '.tpl.php')) {
            $template = dirname (__FILE__) . '/templates/' . $slug . '.tpl.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter ('page_template', '_plc_page_template', 99999);
```

The function is still running and returning the template value, but does not render the custom template once on the page.  Does anyone know the way to override the template for OptimizePress?  Thanks.

(The 99999 weight value was me just trying to get it to fire after OptimizePress.)

Answer (score 1):

Had to switch the filter to the ***template_include*** hook.  Don't know if that is the correct way to do it, but it works:

```
function _plc_template_include ($template) {
    $pages = _plc_get_custom_pages();
    foreach ($pages as $slug => $title) {
        if (is_page ($slug) && is_file (PLC_TEMPLATES . $slug . '.tpl.php')) {
            ob_start();
            include PLC_TEMPLATES . $slug . '.tpl.php';
            $content = ob_get_clean();
            include PLC_TEMPLATES . 'content.tpl.php';
            return;
        }
    }
    include $template;
}
add_filter ('template_include', '_plc_template_include', 99999);
```

I placed the content of the template into a variable and placed all the content into one template to avoid rewriting the header and footer each time, but easily could have just put:

```
include PLC_TEMPLATES . $slug . '.tpl.php';
return;
```

instead of the ob_start & ob_get_clean methods.